# The converse of Hensel's lemma

Tags: number-theory

I know the following version of Hensel's Lemma.

> Hensel's Lemma: Suppose $p$ is an odd prime, $a \not \equiv 0 \pmod p$ and $j \ge 1$. If we have a solution $x_j$ to the equation
>
> $$a \equiv x_j^2 \pmod {p^j}$$
>
> then there exists a unique solution to the equation
>
> $$a \equiv x_{j+1}^2 \pmod {p^{j+1}}$$
>
> that satisfies $x_j \equiv x_{j+1} \pmod {p^j}$.

I am asking myself if the converse is also true, meaning:

> If there is a solution $x_{j+1}$
> to $$a \equiv x_{j+1}^2 \pmod {p^{j+1}}$$
> then there is unique solution $x_j$ to the equation
> $$a \equiv x_j^2 \pmod {p^j}.$$

I suspect that this converse is not true, but I cannot find a counterexample to it. Could you help me?

Comment: Why not $x_j=x_{j+1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p^{j + 1} \mid a - x_{j + 1}^2$ then $p^j \mid a - x_{j + 1}^2$.

Comment: AHHH, ok that solves it. Thanks for your help.